# Syntax to export a variable using module.exports

Tags: node.js

I would like to export the variable `db` so it would be available in app.js

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var config = require('./config');
console.log(config);
var database = require('./services/database')(config);
database.connect(...) // database is undefined
```

**Exception: TypeError: Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined**

**config.js**

```
var config = module.exports;
config.mongodb = {
  port: process.env.MONGODB_PORT || 27017,
  host: process.env.MONGODB_HOST || 'localhost',
  db: "test"
};
```

**services/database.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
    console.log(config);
    var dburl = config.mongodb.host + ":" + config.mongodb.port + "/" + config.mongodb.db + "?auto_reconnect";
    console.log(dburl);
    var db = mongoskin.db(dburl);
    // I want to export db
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would export an object which has db property.
That object may have other properties (function/data) too.
This sample code exports an object with a function property fun and a data property db.

```
module.exports = function(param) {
  return {
    fun : function() {
       // whatever code is needed
    },
    db : {
       // whatever data is needed
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding sample code to achieve that? My main problem is the syntax to use

Answer (score 1):

Node cache modules' value so it's always will return same db instance.

**services/database.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
    console.log(config);
    var dburl = config.mongodb.host + ":" + config.mongodb.port + "/" + config.mongodb.db + "?auto_reconnect";
    console.log(dburl);
    var db = mongoskin.db(dburl);

    return db;
};
```

Also, you don't need to database.connect in app.js, because you are already connected in **services/database.js**.